# returnUrl always null even when getting the login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, authorization

I see that this has been asked quite a lot but the solution is always for posting the form. I'm not even getting a value when redirecting to my custom login page.
Here's my LoginController

```
// GET: /Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

and custom UserAuthorize filter

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // If they are authorized, handle accordingly
        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise redirect to your specific authorized area
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using custom authorizing method, then you must add`returnUrl` parameter manually. Normally, `FormsAuthentication` class handles adding this parameter to the QueryString.

```
var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

// Get return url if it exist
if (request.HttpMethod.Equals("GET", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    returnUrl = request.RawUrl;

filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
         new
         {
               controller = "Login",
               action = "Index",
               ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
         }));
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you

Comment: @user3112059 Glad to help.